# Why can't Mathematica express a minus operation between two decimal numbers with several places?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, numerical-value, precision-and-accuracy

[image: example]A example of the problem. This is a print from mathematica with the demonstration of the issue.

Comment: Perhaps you want `Round[Sqrt[2], 10^-37] - Round[Sqrt[2], 10^-20]`.

Comment: `N` computes `Sqrt[2]` in discrete steps, and several digits at each step. The extra digits are kept. In fact `FullForm[y]` shows `y` has around 59 digits. It is similar with `z`.  `SetPrecision[y, 59] - SetPrecision[z, 59]` shows the actual difference of the internal point estimates for `Sqrt[2]` is about `6.8*10^-40`. It is unlikely you will want to use `N` for your purpose because the point estimate for `N[Sqrt[2], 24]` is the same as the one for `N[Sqrt[2], 20]`. It's hard to know when it's going to change. Its goal is to produce one that is **at least** as accurate as requested.

Comment: For this example your suggestion works. I'll try to another cases. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

The `N` function approximates an exact number to the specified number of decimal places.  The result tracks the precision of the answer.

So when you compute `y-z` the result is only valid to 20 decimal places (since that is the uncertainty in `z`), all of which are zero.

Note that specifying `N` on an approximate number cannot increase the accuracy of the result - it cannot invent digits that it doesn't have.

Comment: My interest is in investigating the propagation of error in numerical precision for irrational numbers. MAPLE is capable of numerically expressing this difference in precision between numbers. I did the same example on MAPLE. I thought Mathematica could do the same.

Comment: Mathematica uses a different paradigm for getting numerical results. It can increase precision during a calculation as needed. Please read the documentation.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you blew off the excellent comment from Michael E2, but expanding on that a little bit:

```
Round[a, 10^-37] - Round[a, 10^-20] // N[#, 37 - 20] &
(*1.6887242096980786*10^-21*)
```